# While loop not reading the current length of array object (angular 6)

Tags: angular, typescript

im trying to splice array into parts and already achieve what i want but i added some filters to only add in the list array (lf) that has only (4) action status and the while loop cant read the length of array

Heres my code:

```
  lf = [];
  rows = [];
  size = 4;
  logframes$: any;

  constructor(private logframe: LogicalframeworkService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.logframe.getLogicalFrameworks().subscribe(
      data => this.setTitle(data)
    );
  }

  setTitle(array) {
    array.forEach(item => {
      const card = {
        'id': item.id,
        'title': item.project.description
      };
      this.logframe.getAuditTrailStatusByLogFrame(item.id).subscribe(
        (data: any) => {
          if (data.logFrameActionStatusReferenceId === 4) {
            this.lf.push(card);
            console.dir(this.lf);
          }
        }
      );
    });
    while (this.lf.length > 0) {
      this.rows.push(this.lf.splice(0, this.size));
    }
  }
```

Comment: May be your logic is wrong

Comment: What the final output for `console.dir(this.lf);`

Answer (score 0):

While loop code will get executed before the 'logframe' service returns data. Updated code. Also why you need while loop for length check. you can achieve it using if cond.

```
lf = [];
  rows = [];
  size = 4;
  logframes$: any;

  constructor(private logframe: LogicalframeworkService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.logframe.getLogicalFrameworks().subscribe(
      data => this.setTitle(data)
    );
  }

  setTitle(array) {
    array.forEach(item => {
      const card = {
        'id': item.id,
        'title': item.project.description
      };
      this.logframe.getAuditTrailStatusByLogFrame(item.id).subscribe(
        (data: any) => {
          if (data.logFrameActionStatusReferenceId === 4) {
            this.lf.push(card);
            console.dir(this.lf);
            if (this.lf.length) {
              this.rows.push(this.lf.splice(0, this.size));
            }

          }
        }
      );
    });

  }
```

Comment: i need lf array to complete first so that i can group it by 4 by using splice so that it is not hard for me to use row and col for bootstrap at template side of angular